# Requirement for prana pratishthana

Tags: pranapratishtha

For purpose of worship in temples, idols made from metal, wood or soil are created and the ritual of prana pratishthana, i.e. inviting God to be present in the idol, is done. In Sanatana Dharma it is believed that God is present in each and every anu or atom. This being the case, God is present in the idol. Then what is the need for doing prana pratishthana?

Comment: To localize its presence you need to do that. If you think God is present everywhere why to do idol worship in the first place. Although God is present everywhere, when you are worshipping him you need to do it in an "adhAra" which might be fire, water or image/idol.